# multiple react-select make it so a array item can only be selected once

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-select

I have a page where you can select categories and if you press a categorie you can select subcategories.
What I'm trying to build is that a categorie can only be selected once.
I can't use multi on just one react-select because of the subcategories.

So what I get is a array of categories. and I get the selected item and can splice it from the list.
But I don't know how to put the previous selected one back in the list.

What I tried:
prevState but because there are multiple selects, if you have three selects you can still get doubles.
I have tried to use findIndex to search for the previous selected one and if it already exists don't put it back in the list but I'm also stuck here.

Category array:

```
Categories = [{'value': 1, 'label': "category_1"}, {'value': 2, 'label': "category_2"}, {'value': 3, 'label': "category_3"}]
```

[image]
*lang is dutch

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated My original answer so that the amount of categories and amount of category selects can be dynamic.
You can check the link in the comments for a working sample.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
    import "./styles.css";
    
    export default function App() {
      let categories = [
        { value: "1", label: "category_1" },
        { value: "2", label: "category_2" },
        { value: "3", label: "category_3" }
      ];
    
      const [categorySelects, updateCategorySelects] = useState([
        {
          id: 1,
          text: "select category",
          selectedValue: 0
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          text: "select category",
          selectedValue: 0
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          text: "select category",
          selectedValue: 0
        }
      ]);
    
      const categorySelectHandler = (val, id) => {
        let categorySelectArr = categorySelects.map((cs) => {
          if (cs.id == id) {
            cs.selectedValue = val;
          }
          return cs;
        });
        updateCategorySelects(categorySelectArr);
      };
    
      const checkAvailability = (val) => {
        let isAvailable = true;
        categorySelects.forEach((cs) => {
          if (val == cs.selectedValue) {
            isAvailable = false;
          }
        });
        return isAvailable;
      };
      return (
        <div className="App">
          {categorySelects.map((cs) => {
            return (
              <div>
                {cs.text}
                <select
                  onChange={(event) =>
                    categorySelectHandler(event.target.value, cs.id)
                  }
                  value={cs.selectedValue}
                >
                  <option value={0}>Selecteer categorie</option>
                  {categories
                    .filter(
                      (c) =>
                        checkAvailability(c.value) || c.value == cs.selectedValue
                    )
                    .map((c) => (
                      <option value={c.value}>{c.label}</option>
                    ))}
                </select>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Created a quick example for you.
https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-fire-46fqq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thanks for the help, on the page a user can add select fields so the id is not static like in your example

Comment: That really shouldn't make a difference, 
just depends on how you initiate and update state.
If you splice the selected one from the array, the <select> element used to select the item in the first place won't have access to the value either. Which is why you should filter it when printing in to the DOM.

You need to manage the value of those 3 selects in state, so you know the selected items (value).
You can then filter before mapping on that state.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-tree-ehy9m?file=/src/App.js